# Set DEFAULT value on a column, based on the compute of another column

Tags: sql, date, set, default

EDIT:**I'M USING SQL-Oracle Database 10g**
I need to set one column DATE value (loan_due), based on another DATE column(loan_date).

**The thing is, "loan_due" has to be exactly the next month of "loan_date" and the DAY has to be 5.**

EXAMPLE:

IF loan_date IS '**12/06/14**', the loan_due HAS TO BE '**05/07/14**'(This have to take place,just right after I insert loan_Date)

IF loan_date IS '**01/09/14**', the loan_due HAS TO BE '**05/10/14**'

I think a TRIGGER could help, but when i try, I only get "Mutating table" errors.. because the trigger try to DML the table in which is working.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't provide.

Comment: Oh.. s**t. Sorry, it's my first day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to set a column on the same row that's being INSERTed or UPDATEd, then a BEFORE INSERT or BEFORE UPDATE trigger is the way to go.

In the body of the trigger, for **MySQL** you just do something like this:

```
 SET NEW.loan_due = LAST_DAY(NEW.loan_date) + INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

After the trigger is fired, When the statement proceeds, the `loan_due` column will have the value that was set in the trigger, and the INSERT or UPDATE will proceed using that value.

For **Oracle**, it's much the same. In the body of the `BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW` trigger, assign a value to the column. The assignment syntax is different in PL/SQL:

```
NEW.loan_due := expr ;
```

Where `expr` is an expression that returns the 5th day of the month, following `NEW.loan_date`.

Comment: I've commented on my own answer beacuse I dont know how to write a smaller coment, i wanted to.. kinda "quote" you, i don't know if I can do that here. I'ts embarassing.

Comment: The example I gave would work in **MySQL**, not **Oracle**. For Oracle, you need to do the assignment differently, using the PL/SQL assignment operator, and a different expression.